# How to get mail alert for pipeline status using Alert rule

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm trying to check the status of pipeline succeeded or failed for daily, how can i get email alert from data factoty altert rule using. what is the process.

I'm trying to check the status of pipeline succeeded or failed for daily, how can i get email alert from data factoty altert rule using. what is the process, please share screen shots for using Alert rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use alerts in the Data factory.

Go to **Monitor->Alerts & metrics** and create new alert.

Add the severity and **Add criteria**.

[image]

Add the criteria for the failed pipeline runs.

[image]

Now, give your **pipeline name** and **Failure Type**. Give the alert condition as per your requirement.

[image]

Add other criteria for the Pipeline succeed as well like above.

Next, click on **configure notification** and create a new action group for it. After this, give your mail id by **Add notification**.

[image]

[image]

Click on **create alert rule** and the alert will be created. The mail will be triggered as per the criteria like below.

[image]

**Reference**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-metrics-alerts

Comment: In 3rd screenshot, pipeline name disabled, how can I do enable that one

Comment: I think you need to publish the pipeline.

Comment: Yes, publish not done. Without publish how can I do

Comment: No, without publishing the pipeline, pipeline won't reflect in the alerts.