# Log Azure data factory and azure databricks

Tags: azure, logging, azure-data-factory, databricks

I'm looking for feedback on how to professionally manage logs in Azure Data Factory and Azure Databricks, similar to how it's typically done in enterprises. On my end, I have an Azure Data Factory pipeline that executes Databricks notebooks. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide what you have tried so far? sample input and expected input? where you wanna store the logs?

Comment: I have ADF pipelines that execute Databricks notebooks. I'm looking to implement logging in my workflow using enterprise-standard practices. For instance, I'd like to receive an email notification if a pipeline encounters an error. I'm not sure how this is typically done professionally. (I have a project bronze layer / silver layer / golf layer ) and a mount point to use data ifrom ADLS into databricks

Comment: So, your requirement is to get a mail when this pipeline fails right?

Comment: No, what I'm actually looking for is someone who can share their experience or provide a solution on how to implement logs in a data project using ADF to execute Databricks notebooks. I want to have logs from both ADF and Databricks but using a method commonly used in enterprises, not just a solution that meets the current need. Thank you.

Comment: Where you wanna store the logs? in a Storage account?

Comment: I don’t know I want to store the logs; where is it recommended to store them

Comment: I am just asking what are you going to do with logs? You wanna query them? Monitor them? or export them?

Comment: To consult them when there is an execution problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are some of the ways to manage the logs of ADF pipelines.

**Export logs to log analytics workspace or storage account:**

Go to ADF **Monitor** -> **Diagnostic settings** -> **add diagnostic setting**.

Create the diagnostic setting like below.

[image]

You can send the logs to a log analytics workspace or any storage account as per your requirement. Provide the subscription and resource names like above and save it.

The logs will be saved in the storage account like below.

[image]

In this JSON, the pipeline runs logs will be stored in this JSON. It will be automatically updated as per the pipeline runs from ADF. If any error arises, you can check the logs from this JSON.

**The same logs will be stored in the Log analytics workspace** as well. Go to the workspace and you can query logs using KQL.

**If you want to get alert mails** based on the pipeline runs, you can create **alert rules** for that.

[image]

Go through this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77678298/18836744) to learn more about it.

You can use the above ways to manage the logs as per your requirement. Check this [blog](https://climbtheladder.com/10-azure-data-factory-logging-best-practices/) by @[Marjory Shrader](https://climbtheladder.com/users/3493/profile/marjory-shrader) to know about remaining ways.

**UPDATE:**

The JSON file will hold the pipeline runs information as an array of Objects. This is one pipeline run in that array.

```
{ "EventName": "DiagnosticsLogs", "category": "PipelineRuns", "correlationId": "39ebbb88-9ccd-450d-a1f7-d80c16b774a0", "end": "2024-01-29T06:50:30.0000000Z", "env_dt_spanId": "6a64f8994ea499b4", "env_dt_traceId": "f3b88fa27eb81f538dd3d269e834dd4f", "env_name": "DiagnosticsLogsSource", "env_time": "2024-01-29T06:50:30.8557880Z", "env_ver": "4.0", "failureType": "UserError", "groupId": "39ebbb88-9ccd-450d-a1f7-d80c16b774a0", "level": "Error", "location": "eastus", "name": "DiagnosticsLogs", "operationName": "pipeline1 - Failed", "pipelineName": "pipeline1", "properties": {  "Parameters": {},  "SystemParameters": {    "ExecutionStart": "2024-01-29T06:50:29.8345435Z",    "TriggerId": "8863785bddc94a4ca3acdaebcacee774",    "SubscriptionId": "<sub_id>",    "PipelineRunRequestTime": "2024-01-29T06:50:28.8629073+00:00"  },  "Predecessors": [    {      "Name": "Manual",      "Id": "8863785bddc94a4ca3acdaebcacee774",      "InvokedByType": "Manual"    }  ],  "UserProperties": {},  "Annotations": [],  "Message": "Operation on target Set variable1 failed: The variable 'var1' of type 'String' cannot be initialized or updated with value of type 'Integer'. The variable 'var1' only supports values of types 'String'."}, "resourceId": "/SUBSCRIPTIONS/<sub_id>/RESOURCEGROUPS/<RG_name>/PROVIDERS/MICROSOFT.DATAFACTORY/FACTORIES/RAKESHDFACTORY", "runId": "39ebbb88-9ccd-450d-a1f7-d80c16b774a0", "severityNumber": 9, "severityText": "Information", "start": "2024-01-29T06:50:28.0000000Z", "status": "Failed", "tags": "{\"Reason\":\"Repro\",\"CreatedDate\":\"1/29/2024 6:05:37 AM\",\"CreatedBy\":\"NA\",\"OwningTeam\":\"NA\"}", "timestamp": "2024-01-29T06:50:30.0000000Z", "time": "2024-01-29T06:50:30.8557880Z"}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your detailed response. Can you share the JSON code with me, or can I use it?

Regarding the logs of Databricks notebooks, if there are exceptions in my code, will they be in this JSON file as well?

Comment: I have given a sample pipeline run in the Update section of my answer. Please check that. And coming to databricks logs, whatever the error or exception that your notebook gives, upon execution of those from ADF, it will store the notebook error message text https://i.imgur.com/2zUiG0m.png in the `message` section of the above JSON. you can check the error by going to that URL in that message.